# Hide input empty input upon Submit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide empty  fields upon submit $_GET.

My code looks like this but it's not working. Any help with the logic of this would be great.

```
<script>
$(submit).click(function(){
if(input.value.length == 0)
    input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:
Here is my button which submits the form -

```
<input name="SaveBtn" type="submit" id="SaveBtn" 
formaction="update1Profile.php?id="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>
<?php echo $_GET['source_ID'] ?>" formmethod="GET" value="Save">
```

Comment: what is `submit` here. Is this refers html element? post your html code.

Comment: This is client-side code.  As soon as the page is submitted any state set by this code will be lost when the page refreshes.

Comment: @David it's possible that the form submission is supposed to trigger an ajax call that won't result in the page being overwritten.

Comment: Submit is the 'type' of input button that submits the form. The actual input button I am using is named 'saveBTN' and is written like so: <input name="SaveBtn" type="submit" id="SaveBtn" formaction="update1Profile.php?id="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?><?php echo $_GET['source_ID'] ?>" formmethod="GET" value="Save">

Comment: @Pointy: Which is why that was a comment and not an answer.  It's also possible that `submit` is undefined, or `input` is undefined, or jQuery isn't loaded, or...  I think we're going to need more meaningful information in this question.

Comment: @MizAkita: Is this the *exact* code you're using?  Can you elaborate on "not working"?  Are there any errors in the browser console?  Is the click event handler executing?  Is the jQuery selector for the click event handler even finding any elements?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys. I just updated my question with my button code.

Comment: @MizAkita you're using "submit" and "input" as if they were variables.  There's no evidence in the code you posted that they actually are.

Comment: I am getting "Submit is not defined" with the above code...

Comment: @Pointy i need this function to apply to any empty input. How would I define all <input>'s?

Comment: @MizAkita it's in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Well that code is probably giving you errors in the browser console; it's always a good idea to check there first.

You need to *find* the `<input>` elements, and just mentioning the word "input" won't do that. Same goes for your "submit" element, whatever that is.  That might look something like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('input').filter(function() { return this.value == ''; }).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

*edit* — in a comment below, the OP now mentions that he wants to avoid having the empty inputs submitted. If that's the case, then making them invisible will definitely not do that. Instead (or additionally), it's necessary to mark the fields as "disabled":

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('input')
    .filter(function() { return this.value == ''; })
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: I tried this with the following:  $('#LName').find('input').filter(function() { return LName.value == ''; }).css('visibility', 'hidden'); but it seems to be now ignoring all updates and no errors are coming into my console. Hmmm... the $(this) is actually $('#Lname')

Comment: It should not be `LName.value == '';` it should be `this.value == '';` as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: This seems to work but it still sends an empty field to my database which deletes the entry that is there already! Any way to completely ignore the $_GET if empty?

Comment: @MizAkita making a field not visible **does not prevent it from being submitted.** If you want to do that, you have to **disable** the field as well.

Comment: Hmm... just tried it, instead it does not submit the form. Only if there is something presently in the LName field. If that area is empty, it just ignores the submit.  There has got to be a way to achieve this. All i am trying to do is not submit the fields that ARE null! I'd like to skip posting these fields to the DB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38738/discussion-between-mizakita-and-pointy)

Answer (score 0):

use `display` instead of `visibility`, assuming you defined `input` somewhere in that code

```
input.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Visibility and display are two different things, this might cause unexpected behaviour with element shifting.